# Android relative layout center vertical with margin

Tags: android, layout, center, margin, vertical-alignment

in Android's RelativeLayout we can set textView exact in the center of the screen with this code:

```
<TextView
    android:text="This is TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

result:

```
top
-
-
-
-
This is TextView (center vertical)
-
-
-
-
bottom
```

But I need the textView to be a little bit to the bottom, I try add `marginTop` but seems like after using `layout_centerVertical=true` its become impossible. Any solution?

Expected result (a little bit to bottom):

```
top
-
-
-
-
-
-
This is TextView (center vertical slight to bottom)
-
-
bottom
```

Comment: great question, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use LinearLayout which can easily done your requirement using weight :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <TextView
            android:text="This is TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It can be done using only the relativelayout, without the need to have a complicated view hierarchy. see my answer below

Comment: @amarkovits,I think you not see all ans please check all ans some one already as your type solution so try to upvote this instead of putting your reputed ans.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

Try to use RelativeLayout which can easily done your requirement using weight :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
      <TextView
          android:id="@id/dummy"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
      <TextView
          android:layout_below="@id/dummy"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:text="This is TextView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

Why should **add nested view** inside **parent view** ?

Use `paddingTop` attribute.

**Example:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlParentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: this doesnt work if width and height has a fixed value like 50dp

Answer (score 4):

If you are not going to make a translate animation for the view, you can use the `android:translationY` attribute to push it as much as you want (negative value for pushing up)

Comment: I don't know the reason for anyone down-voting this answer but this is exactly what would work without using complex hierarchy or space attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this kind of problem today and I figured out this way. `Sapce` and `LinearLayout` is a good solution to do this.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/base_background_color">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/base_toolbar_color"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>

    <!-- using LinearLayout to align ProgressBar to center vertical -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/other_profile_progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```